# How can I block on an EventMachine deferrable object?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, sinatra, eventmachine

I'm making a request to another server as part of a POST method to my Sinatra application. The library I'm using to make the request is an EventMachine library that immediately returns an EM::Deferrable object when a request is made, but I need to block in the controller method until the asynchronous request completes so I can return a partial with data returned in the request. What's the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Are you using an EM webserver like Thin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra) and an EM based webserver like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/). With async_sinatra you would have a `body` method for explicit rendering. It would work like this:

```
require 'sinatra/async'
require 'em-http-request'

class Application < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  apost '/' do
    http = EM::HttpRequest.new('http://www.google.de/').get

    http.callback do
      body do
        # your http processing in here, will be rendered
      end
    end

    http.errback do
      body { 'error' }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you block on an evented API, you get worst of the two worlds.

I would try to avoid calls through EM in favor of more 'traditional' methods (a-la curl).

If this is not possible, then I would return an empty partial and have client poll the server for updates.